# combining Strings from txt files

Tags: java

I've got two txt files consisting of names (1st) and surnames (2nd). I'm trying to combine those two in a way that: every name is combined with every surname. I thought about Stringbuffer and then ...? This is just for personal use, so any tips would be appreciated.

```
public class test {


public static void main(String[] args) {

        String anArray[] = new String[10];

        anArray[0] = "John";
        anArray[1] = "Paul"; 
        anArray[2] = "Mike";

        String anArray2[] = new String[10];

        anArray2[0] = "Smith";
        anArray2[1] = "Johnson";
        anArray2[2] = "Simpson";

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {

        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {

            String combined = anArray[i].concat(anArray2[j]);
            System.out.println(combined);

        }
        }



}
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Stack Overflow is more intended for questions you encounter once you actually begin your application, such as *how to read a file* or something of the sort.  Voted to close.

Comment: `StringBuilder` is a un-synchronized version of `StringBuffer` (basically it's not thread safe), which will give you a slight performance boast. Even if it is for personal use, I would still encourage you to use good practices.  String manipulation of this type is generally best handled by `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two sets.

You will need to nested loops and to assign in it each first name with its surname

Pseudo code:

```
  for each firstName:
     for each surName:
         print firstName surName
```

Note - the `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` in here won't help much then a simple strint concat - since you are concatting exactly two strings (which you need to create the objects for) - unless you want one string containing all possible names, but I doubt that what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, so that's what I got so far, but I would like to add StringBuilder to it